Merging /dev/mmcblk0 and /dev/mmcblk0p1 in Debian 9 on BeagleBone Black
The BeagleBone Black is running Debian 9.9 from a SD card (128 GB), but it is not using the full space of the SD card.
I am unexperienced when it comes to using Linux and have a minimal understanding. I am learning to use the BeagleBone Black with a DLP Lightcrafter 2000 EVM, and I installed Debian 9.9 (with a GUI) onto a SD card. The BeagleBone boots from the SD card, but it doesn't use all of the space on the SD card, which wasn't an issue when using the latest versions of Debian. Now, I am unable to install any packages, and I receive the message that there is no available space. Running lsblk shows this:
debian@beaglebone:~$ lsblk
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
mmcblk0      179:0    0 117.8G  0 disk
└─mmcblk0p1  179:1    0   3.5G  0 part /
mmcblk1      179:8    0   3.5G  0 disk
└─mmcblk1p1  179:9    0   3.5G  0 part
mmcblk1boot0 179:16   0     2M  1 disk
mmcblk1boot1 179:24   0     2M  1 disk
mmcblk1rpmb  179:32   0   512K  0 disk

Is there a way I could merge mmcblk0 with mmcblk0p1 so that the BeagleBone can utilize the space of the SD card?

I think, you can boot from the embedded MMC1 and use for MMC0 (SD card) the tools such as fdisk, resize2fs etc.

Your question probably would get (better) answers at [unix.se].
